# C# float[] to java float[] via socket

Tags: c#, java, sockets

Please give me some examples (code on both languages) on how to send float array from c# to Java via socket. 
Thanks.

Comment: Alex, this is not how it works here. You don't just ask for code. You show what you did, explain where you hit a problem, and ask for for help. The question how it's worded now is begging the RTFM answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can serialize this array as string [1.25,1.4556,1.34545] and then read this string in Java and de-serialize to array.

I don't like SOAP :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly send them since the two float[] are not interoperable. You have to go for a standard protocol to share them. `SOAP` could be one of them.

Comment: Why aren't they interoperable? They should both be in IEEE format.

Answer (score 1):

Text is likely to be the safest way to pass the data. However you can readFloat() using DataInput or via ByteBuffers. There must be a similar option in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You somehow have to convert your floats on one side to bytes, write them to the output-stream of the socket, read them from the input-stream of the socket, and convert those back to floats.

There is the IEEE 754 standard which defines a bit layout - in Java this is implemented by `Float.floatToIntBits` and `Float.intBitsToFloat`, and also by the `readFloat`/`writeFloat` methods of DataInputStream.

I suppose there will be a similar method on the .NET side, but I don't know anything about this.